# A tribute to Stan Lee

Tags: knowledge, steganography, video-games

[image: Name the Halloween prop in a mineshaft then rot13(tbbtyr) it open the third website then the third word in the thesaurus. which "the third word in thesaurus" is the hottest one in a game by microsoft?]

Start  Here

One answer will lead you to the next question

Comment: (rot 13) hfvat gur fnzr gevpx gjvpr. fzu.

Comment: well but now it is a little different

Comment: As has already been mentioned, your intended route of solving depends on a lot of personalized steps, which we cannot possibly recreate. As such, this is unsolvable. I suggest you write up a different method to avoid being downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 4):

> Well, the hidden text is:
>  Name the Halloween prop in a mineshaft then google it 
>  open the third website then the third word in the thesaurus. which "the third word in thesaurus" is the hottest one in a game by microsoft?
>
>  To get to the text you need to edit the puzzle.
>
>  I guess the Halloween prop is lantern, because you use a lantern in a mine shfat and on Halloween people make pumpkin lanterns.
>  but then we face the google it problem. The results are different depending on the 'google' you use, your settings, etc.
>  I get different results on google.com and google.co.uk  or, rather, google recognises my location and taylors the result for the region.
>  So for me this is ill defined puzzle

Comment: Hidden what now? Could you add some explanation (spoiler tagged of course) as to how you've got this far?

Comment: @Astralbee Please see my edit.